# Creating namespaces in ES6 module with multiple files. Bad idea?

Tags: javascript, module, ecmascript-6

I have a library with multiple files that are currently concatenated into a single file with Gulp. Each of these files set a property of the main library object `Rune`, so `color.js` will set `Rune.Color`, `math.js` will set `Rune.Math`, and so on.

This is obviously old school, so I want to rewrite it all using ES6 modules, and use Gulp, Browserify and Babel to create the compiled bundle.

However, I will then end up with a compiled library where the namespaces are gone, and people will need to do `import color from "rune"` to use the color module.

So, I was thinking about doing this is my main module file:

```
import color from "./color"

const Rune = {
  Color: color
}

export default Rune;
```

Is that a terrible idea? The module is already used in the main file, so I can't really see any downside to it.

Comment: Found this: http://www.mattburkedev.com/export-a-global-to-the-window-object-with-browserify/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is that a terrible idea?

Having an entry point to your library and exporting all methods from there is not a bad idea. However, I would stick with ES6 imports and exports:

```
// Rune.js
export {default as color} from './color';
```

Now clients can use:

```
import {color} from 'rune';
```

or

```
import * as Rune from 'rune';
```

to import what they need.

Comment: This is really awesome. Thanks!